# How should we set classpath URL's to URLClassLoader?

Tags: java

I have this piece of code:

```
URLClassLoader tmp = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { getClassPath() });

private static URL getClassPath() {
    return new URL("/home/rudik/workspace/cl/target/classes/");
}
```

I got `/home/rudik/workspace/cl/target/classes/` from `Arrays.toString(((URLClassLoader) MyClass.class.getClassLoader()).getURLs())` execution.

When I execute it I get this exception:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /home/rudik/workspace/cl/target/classes/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't pass a URL string to the `URL` constructor. In your case it should be

```
private static URL getClassPath() {
    return new URL("file:///home/rudik/workspace/cl/target/classes/");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Steffen Kreutz!